# Can in specific situations

Tags: modal-verbs

I have read in Raymond Murphy's "English Grammar in Use" "We use "could" to say that something is possible now or in the future.

1. "The phone is ringing. It could be Tim." "Can" is not possible in these examples. Not "It can be Tim."

In "English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince I read that "can" is correct when something is possible in a general sense: 2. "Learning a language can be difficult." 3. "You can take a train here. There's one every hour."

But in "English Grammar in Context Advanced" I read: "We use "can" or "could" when we ask questions about possibility.
"Who can/could that be outside Mr. Smith's office?"

Does it mean than in sentence #1 I could also use "can" if I was asking a question?
"The phone is ringing. Can/could it be Tim?" And in other examples too, "Can/could learning a language be difficult?" "Could/can I take a train here?"

Comment: Yes, you can. "Could it be Tim?" suggests that you are very eager to hear from him!

Comment: However, you'd never say, "The phone is ringing. It can be Tim."

Comment: Kate Bunting, do you mean there is a difference between *can* and *could* in such case? Does *can*  suggest that I am not eager to hear from him unlike *could*?

Comment: @FeliniusRex, *can* can be used in questions and in negative sentences but not in statements. Right? "Can/could it be Tim? It can't be Tim." Can/could learning a language be difficult?" "Could/can I take a train here?"  But are  "It could not be Tim"  instead of *can*? and  "Could I take a train"? Instead of "Can I take a train" correct?

Comment: @AntoniaA It's not that way. *Could* suggests possibility instead of certainty. In the case of a phone ringing, you have no idea if it is Tim or not. That's why you say *It could be Tim.* Also, *can* grants permission. You're not granting permission for the caller to be Tim, because you can't control that.

Comment: *Could* suggests possibility in the phone example and in these examples too, doesn't it?  "Can/could learning a language be difficult?" "Could/can I take a train here?" Either *can* or *could* is correct in them. Is that right?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. Both 'Can it be...?' and 'Could it be...?' suggest more eagerness than 'It might be Tim' or 'Perhaps it's Tim'.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.  Can I use them in questions in these examples too;  "Can/could learning a language be difficult?" "Could/can I take a train here?" Do both *can* and *could* express possibility in both examples?